# Simple example on how to receive an AWS IOT topic on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm looking for a *simple* JavaScript example of how to receive messages from a topic. I'm trying to create a Build Cop using CodeBuild, Lambda, SNS, and finally, IoT. I've successfully published messages to the topic, but I can't for the life of me figure out what to do to receive the message.

The examples in the SDK are not well-documented (to me at least) and I can't figure out which import to use or why, and how to subscribe to a simple topic.

The code to *send* the message to the thing is the following. I'm sending it from a Lambda. The code is written in TypeScript, but I'm copying and pasting the transpiled JavaScript into the console since it does not seem to support TypeScript natively.

```
const params = {
  topic: 'topic/buildcop',
  payload: color,
  qos: 1
};


this.iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log(`error: ${err}`);
  }
  else{
    console.log("success?");
    //context.succeed(event);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question on what you are asking. You mention subscribe to a topic, receive a message, etc. Include the code that you have written and what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Basically, all  my current code is focused on turning the red, yellow, and green lights on and off on the Pi. I don't have any code yet for reading the topic because I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've registered the Pi as a thing in the AWS Console, and my JavaScript (TypeScript code, really) related to receiving the messages boils down to a single statement right now:

    const awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

I have the device SDK installed. I've been able to "connect" to IoT by running the examples, but they're so poorly-documented, I'm not sure why or how.

Comment: My lambda code--the code that's sending to the thing---is the following:  

    `const params = {`
    `  topic: 'topic/buildcop',`
    `  payload: color,`
    `  qos: 1`
    `};`
   ` `
    ` `
    `this.iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){`
     ` if(err){`
     `   console.log('error:' + err);`
     ` }`
     ` else{`
     `   console.log("success?");`
     `   //context.succeed(event);`
     ` }`
   ` });`

Comment: Sorry for the crummy formatting. I'm trying to use the markdown, but it's not working for me. Maybe I should give up computers and become a hermit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but here is an example on how to subscribe to a topic using the javascript sdk:

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

//
// Replace the values of '<YourUniqueClientIdentifier>' and '<YourCustomEndpoint>'
// with a unique client identifier and custom host endpoint provided in AWS IoT.
// NOTE: client identifiers must be unique within your AWS account; if a client attempts 
// to connect with a client identifier which is already in use, the existing 
// connection will be terminated.
//
var device = awsIot.device({
   keyPath: <YourPrivateKeyPath>,
  certPath: <YourCertificatePath>,
    caPath: <YourRootCACertificatePath>,
  clientId: <YourUniqueClientIdentifier>,
      host: <YourCustomEndpoint>
});

//
// Device is an instance returned by mqtt.Client(), see mqtt.js for full
// documentation.
//
device
  .on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connect');
    device.subscribe('topic_1');
    device.publish('topic_2', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1}));
  });

device
  .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
    console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
  });
```

You can see more examples at here: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#jobs

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by UniqueClientIdentifier and CustomEndpoints?

Comment: UniqueClientIdentifier is a unique clientId you create for your device, can be any string that uniquely identifies your device. The custom endpoint is the AWS IoT host, you can find it on the AWS IoT dashboard on "Settings".

Comment: Helpful note: it took me a while to figure out why this was silently "failing." Before testing you need to go into your IOT Policies, and be sure the client is allowed to pub/sub